# Wordpress - stop featured images from being cropped?

Tags: wordpress

How do I stop the featured image of my posts from being cropped?

This is the closest code I've found on functions.php:

function thickbox_fields($form_fields, $post){
    unset(
        $form_fields['image-size']
    );

```
$size = 'full';
$css_id = "image-size-{$size}-{$post->ID}";
$html = "<div style='display: none;' class='image-size-item'><input type='radio' name='attachments[$post->ID][image-size]' id='{$css_id}' value='{$size}'checked='checked' /></div>";
//set as image-size field
$form_fields['image-size'] = array(
    'label' => '', //leave with no label
    'input' => 'html', //input type is html
    'html' => $html //the actual html
);

return $form_fields;
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
  You should use following code in function.php:

      Syntax: add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop );

      Example: add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 220, 180, false );

  If $crop is set to be "true" then it will be cropped.

  Try it and inform me what happened?
```